# Ext JS tab panel detect tab destroy

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc, tabpanel

How can I detect when a tab in a tab panel is destroyed?
There seems to be no event for that (only for tab and title change)

I know I can listen on 'destroy' event of the components that I am using as tabs, and that works, but I need to do this from MVC controller. I am thinking a right control query may do it, but am not sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent tab panel should fire `beforeremove` event which you can catch in your controller.

Comment: Wouldn't hiding also fire this event?